# How can i maintain a session using php PHPSESSID

Tags: php, sessionid

I am using Scriptable web browser (simplebrowser) http://www.lastcraft.com/browser_documentation.php
and it does not seem to have a way to:

1. session_start();
2. set the PHPSESSID value
3. Browse to few pages using simplebrowser
4. session_destroy();

so it might be possible to use php functions to setup and maintain a session using PHPSESSID

Comment: Do you mean using simplebrowser with cookies?

Comment: yes, using simplebrowser with cookies, could not figure out how to set session id and there is no example. i was looking for session_start() in simplebrowser. Maybe i missed the obvious.

Comment: If simplebrowser uses some kind of user agent, it should be able to deal with cookies. `session_start()`, etc. are completely serverside and have no effect when used in the simplebrowser script.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The session is started by the script that you request with simplebrowser. Lets assume you call example.com/script.php with simplebrowser. Then script.php contains session_start() and thus sends a cookie along with the response. You do not have to start and maintain a session for simplebrowser, let alone set the SID yourself.

Comment: Hi rik, let me explain this a bit more, so i actually make sense. The php script is driven by a shell script, which sets the session id, but first getting it manually from a regular browser session using firebug, and then inserting it into the command line. What i want to achieve is to get the sessionID within the php script using simplebrowser, so i dont have to manually get the value ofPHPSESSID every time i run the shell script, to execute the php script. here is the shell script: #!/bin/bash

i="0"

echo ""
echo "##################"
echo "LAUNCHING REQUESTS"
echo "  COUNT:  $2 "
echo "  DE

Comment: <code>
#!/bin/bash

i="0"

echo ""
echo "##################"
echo "LAUNCHING REQUESTS"
echo "  COUNT:  $2 "
echo "  DELAY:  $3 "
echo "  SESSID: $1"
echo "##################"
echo ""

while [ $2 -gt "$i" ]
do
  i=$[$i+1]
  php avtest.php $1 $4 &
  echo "EXECUTING REQUEST $i"
  sleep $3
done
</code>

Comment: using the API ,<http://simpletest.org/api/>  string getCookieValue (string $host, string $path, string $name) , question is what should i use as the $name , is it PHPSESSID ?

Comment: So you start the session with Firefox, grab the session ID using firebug and pass it to your simplebrowser script as command line parameter. Then you should as well grab and pass the name of the session cookie. You find it in the first column in firebug's cookie tab.

Comment: Oh, and you have to use setCookie (http://simpletest.org/api/SimpleTest/WebTester/SimpleBrowser.html#setCookie), not getCookieValue to setup the instance of simplebrowser.